# How to print row of asterisks in decending order instead of ascending order

Tags: java, for-loop

A program that will request a number as an input from a user between 1 and 9
The program contains: -

1. Validating user entry for correct values
2. Printing row of asterisks as per User input (number of rows is equal to the input provided by the user and in each row the number of asterisks printed decreases by 1)

disclaimer: i am new to coding

I am trying to make the output where the rows of asterisks go in a descending scale
ex:

```
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

But my output right now is the exact opposite
ex:

```
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

Code:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

//For input
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//asking user for a number 
System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 9:     ");
int userNum = input.nextInt();

System.out.println();

// if number is less then 0 or over 9 
if (userNum < 0 || userNum > 9) {
    System.out.println("The number " + userNum + " is not valid.  Try again");
    System.out.print("\nEnter a number from 1 to 9:     ");
    userNum = input.nextInt();
}

String num = "";

// if input is correct
for (int row = 1; row <= userNum; row++)
{
    num += "*";
    System.out.println(num);
}

    } // end main method
} //end class
```

Can you please suggest what's wrong in my code

Thanks

Comment: first of all, the question title is diffrerent from what you wrote in description.

Comment: Change your for loop. 

for ( int row = userNum; row >= 1; row--)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop which starts with the max number of stars and then decreases:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int j=0; j < userNum; ++j) sb.append("*");

for (int i=0; i < userNum; ++i) {
    System.out.println(sb.substring(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string starts empty and you add 1 `*` and print it every time. Thus, you get the widest line at the bottom. Inside you can start with the `userNum` amount of `*` and print it out, then subtract 1 each time.

```java
String num = "";

for (int row = 0; row < userNum; row++) {
    num += "*";
}

for (int row = 0; row < userNum; row++) {
    System.out.println(num);
    num = num.substring(0, num.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will output your desired result.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        for(int i=n;i>=0;i--){          //this loop goes from n->0
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){       //this loop print 1 number of stars
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```